# Trouble with android db

Tags: android, database, listview

I'm making a todo list app and now i'm stuck with this problem and I dont know how to fix it. Can anybody help me.

This is what i'm getting from LogCat:

```
    01-30 12:12:59.044: W/dalvikvm(30917): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.todo/com.todo.Todo}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at com.todo.DatabaseHelper.GetAllItems(DatabaseHelper.java:140)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at com.todo.Todo.setupViews(Todo.java:61)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at com.todo.Todo.onCreate(Todo.java:25)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-30 12:12:59.114: E/AndroidRuntime(30917):    ... 11 more
01-30 12:17:59.188: I/Process(30917): Sending signal. PID: 30917 SIG: 9
```

and i suppose the problem is here:

```
private Button add,delete,search,exit;
    private Intent intent;
    private ListView listView;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db=new DatabaseHelper(this);
        db.open();
        setupViews();
        db.close();

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.main_add_btn:
            //open activity to add item
            intent=new Intent(this, InsertItem.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            break;
        case R.id.main_delete_btn:
            //delete item
            break;
        case R.id.main_exit_btn:
            finish();
            break;

        }

    }
    private void setupViews(){
        add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.main_add_btn);
        delete=(Button) findViewById(R.id.main_delete_btn);
        search=(Button) findViewById(R.id.main_search_btn);
        exit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.main_exit_btn);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        delete.setOnClickListener(this);
        search.setOnClickListener(this);
        exit.setOnClickListener(this);
        listView=getListView();
//      int l=(int) intent.getLongExtra("userID", -1);      
        Log.v("test","tuja");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db.GetAllItems(1));
        Log.v("test","tuja2");
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

This is my first post so sorry if I messed up something

Answer (score 1):

Its clear that arrayindex out of bound exception is in GetAllItems method in databasehelper class, and most likely, it might be generated due to cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));

However, I would suggest you to post you GetAllItems code, so we can help you.

Comment: this is the code of GetAllItems()   `public String[] GetAllItems(int userID) {
  Cursor cur = database.query(true, "todoItems",
    new String[] { "title" }, "userID" + "=" + userID, null, null,
    null, null, null);
  int i;
  String arr[] = new String[40];
  i = 0;

  cur.moveToFirst();
  while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
   arr[i] = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("title"));
   Log.v("test", arr[i]);
   i++;
   cur.moveToNext();
  }
  return arr;
 }`

Comment: can you point out which line throws error, its in 140 inDatabaseHelper.java

Comment: it's this one `arr[i] = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("title"));`

Comment: It has the column title, when I log the results its ok but i't seems the list view is killing me :)

Comment: The problem was the array has length of 40 and the indexes that are null cant be displayed by the listview and that was the error :) . Any ways thank jitendra